# how to create pull request if jenkins job running on feature branch is successful

Tags: git, jenkins, pull-request

Is there a Jenkins plugin for creating pull requests?

Suppose I am running a Jenkins job on some feature branch. If this job is successful, then I want Jenkins to automatically create a pull request from this feature  branch.

There is a command-line way to create pull requests:

```
git request-pull [-p] <start> <url> [<end>]
```

but I haven't been able to find a way to get Jenkins to automate the task.

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins job can have a step calling the [Atlassian Stash API for creating a pull request](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.0/stash-rest.html#idp1424496)

```
POST /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests?direction&at&state&order&withAttributes&withProperties
```

> Create a new pull request between two branches. The branches may be in the same repository, or different ones. When using different repositories, they must still be in the same `{@link Repository#getHierarchyId() hierarchy}`.
>
> The authenticated user must have `REPO_READ` permission for the "`from`" and "`to`" repositories to call this resource.

Comment: @thinkingmonster I have rewritten the answer for Stash

Comment: @thinkingmonster : were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

It is more typical to go the other way: users choose when they are ready to create a pull request, and Jenkins (or any other CI tool) updates the status of the pull request based on the project build result. For example, if you use the GitHub Pull Request Builder, then Jenkins will send a message to GitHub when the project build starts and can close the pull request automatically if the build fails.

Comment: Yeah i understand but i want to do above thing. create pull request when  feature job is success.This is my requirement